# XSLT Sorting A Parent By Two Child Attributes

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am trying to sort parent nodes by two attributes within two separate child elements. Specifically, I want to sort first by "attack/@pct" then by "misc/@pts" Below is my source code:

```
<player uni="11" code="11" name="RACHEL, Devon" checkname="RACHEL,DEVON" class="JR" gp="4" ms="1">
  <attack k="14" e="1" ta="41" pct=".317"></attack>
  <set a="0" e="0" ta="2"></set>
  <serve sa="0" se="0" ta="6"></serve>
  <defense dig="3" re="2" ta="13"></defense>
  <block bs="0" ba="2" be="0" tb="2"></block>
  <misc bhe="0" pts="15.0"></misc>
</player>
<player uni="13" code="13" name="BECKMAN, Allison" checkname="BECKMAN,ALLISON" class="JR" gp="4" ms="1">
  <attack k="3" e="1" ta="4" pct=".500"></attack>
  <set a="51" e="0" ta="128"></set>
  <serve sa="0" se="0" ta="16"></serve>
  <defense dig="17" re="0" ta="0"></defense>
  <block bs="0" ba="2" be="1" tb="2"></block>
  <misc bhe="0" pts="4.0"></misc>
</player>
<player uni="2" code="2" name="MADISON, Kennedy" checkname="MADISON,KENNEDY" class="JR" gp="4">
  <attack k="14" e="7" ta="32" pct=".219"></attack>
  <set a="0" e="0" ta="3"></set>
  <serve sa="0" se="0" ta="0"></serve>
  <defense dig="3" re="0" ta="2"></defense>
  <block bs="0" ba="5" be="0" tb="5"></block>
  <misc bhe="1" pts="16.5"></misc>
</player>
<player uni="20" code="20" name="MUMMEY, Krissy" checkname="MUMMEY,KRISSY" class="SR" gp="4" ms="1">
  <attack k="12" e="4" ta="31" pct=".258"></attack>
  <set a="0" e="0" ta="1"></set>
  <serve sa="0" se="1" ta="8"></serve>
  <defense dig="5" re="0" ta="1"></defense>
  <block bs="0" ba="4" be="1" tb="4"></block>
  <misc bhe="0" pts="14.0"></misc>
</player>
```

Essentially, I want it to spit out the first player even though neither her misc/@pts nor attack/@pct would rank first in either individual sorting. Here's the code I've tried but it seems to be missing something - it'll sort by the first one, but completely disregard the second.

```
<xsl:for-each select="player">
<xsl:sort select="attack/@pct" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
<xsl:sort select="misc/@pts" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: In your example data, every <player> has a distinct value for `attack/@pct`.  The second sort key is therefore irrelevant to this data.

Comment: If you want to sort the data into the order presented, then what is the actual criterion by which the order is determined?  I guess some combination of `attack/@pct` and `misc/@pts`; in that case, it is the *combination* that you want as a sort key.

Comment: I want to sort by attack/@pct and then within that sort, by misc/@pts. Essentially what I'm running into is that the player with the most points isn't always the most efficient - meaning a player with two or three less points could have a attack/@pct substantially higher. Maybe something where it's sorting by attack/@pct while defining a minimum value (greater than) for misc/@pts?

Comment: Example: if Lebron James scores 38 points on 25 shots, but Steph Curry scores 30 points on 15 shots, who would be deemed the more efficient?

Comment: Are you actually saying you want to sort by their average points per shot? So Steph Curry, with an average of 2 points per shot, is sorted before Lebron James, who averages 1.52?

Comment: Tim C - not exactly. The sport in question is actually volleyball - that was just an example. The attack/@pct is their hitting percentage (kills-errors/attack attempts), and the misc/@pts is their total points (kills + aces + blocks). All I'm trying to do is tell it to effectively set a minimum value of .300 for attack/@pct when sorting by misc/@pts. I tried the following but it didn't work:

    <xsl:sort select="attack[@pct&gt;.300]/misc/@pts" data-type="number" order="descending" />

Comment: So, for the XML in your question, only "RACHEL, Devon" and "BECKMAN, Allison" should appear in the output? It might help if you showed the expected output in your question? Thank you.

Comment: I just want to sort the players that have a "attack/@pct" value of at least .300 by "misc/@pts". 

This code works because "@k" falls under the "attack" child:
    <xsl:sort select="attack[@pct&gt;.300]/@k"  data-type="number" order="descending"/>

This code doesn't because it falls under the "misc" child:
    <xsl:sort select="attack[@pct&gt;.300]/misc/@pts" data-type="number" order="descending" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments you *"want to sort the players that have a "attack/@pct" value of at least .300 by "misc/@pts".*  In that case, the expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:sort select="misc[../attack/@pct &gt;= .300]/@pts" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```

Note that the players with a "attack/@pct" less that .300 will still appear in the output, in no particular order, but after the ones that do exceed .300.

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I had a feeling I was on the right track (somewhat) but couldn't quite figure it out on my own.